# Insert into database date range spring boot app

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need some help.
I am working on spring boot app, and I have task to make a reservation system.
My entities are User, WorkStation, Reservation, OfficeRoom.
The problem I can not solve is that I need to make method which will send me data from front and I need to use that input data and store them into table reservations.

The name of method should be:

**makeNewReservation(int userId, int workStationId, LocalDate from, LocalDate to);**

- I have only one field of Class LocalDate in Reservation class, and that is what make me confused.

**This is class reservation:**

[Class Reservation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB7Gj.png)

**Class User**

[Class User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roWsp.png)

**Class WorkStation**

[Class WorkStation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AfPu.png)

**ReservationRepository**

[Repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpQ3M.png)

In this repo I need to make method that will speek with database and store data from that method.
When front send me date range (dateFrom, dateTo), userId, and workStationId, and I have only one field of date into database, how can I store that reservations line by line into table. Each date new row in table.
Example

**saveNewReservation(int userId, int workStationId, LocalDate from, LocalDate to)**

**saveNewReservation(1, 3, 2021-11-29, 2021-12-02)**

in database it should be stored:

1. 1, 3, 2021-11-29
2. 1, 3, 2021-11-30
3. 1, 3, 2021-12-01
4. 1, 3, 2021-12-02

This is how table in mySQL looks like:

[Reservation table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc4hT.png)

Thanks...

Comment: FOr each date in the range create a reservervation and store it.

Comment: Can I write a query in repository for that?

Comment: Why make it more complex than just create those objects and store them? You are overthinking this.

Comment: I do not know how to manage with dates that is the problem. If I want to store values as new reservation every time, how to handle with dates?

Comment: As stated it isn't more complex than creating a **new reservation for each date in the range**. Determine the dates, iterate over them do `new Reservation(props)` and store it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.